# objective C NSString stringwithformat of a URL

Tags: objective-c, nsstring, nsurlrequest

i need my application to send an HTTP request to my server, this is the link, but for some reason, when i create an NSString stringwithformat not all of the string is copied into the string,

this is my URL:

```
http://192.168.50.204:8080/webapi/originate?sofia/internal/408%25192.168.50.204%20'set:effective_caller_id_number=722772408,bridge:sofia/gateway/012smile/<PHONENUMBER>@212.199.220.21'%20inline%200545890183%200545890183
```

if i put it in my browser it is working fine.

and this is the code:

```
self.feedURLString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://192.168.50.204:8080/webapi/originate?sofia/internal/%@%25192.168.50.204%20'set:effective_caller_id_number=722772%@,bridge:sofia/gateway/012smile/%@@212.199.220.21'%20inline%20%@%20%@",extention,extention,PhoneNumber,PhoneNumber, PhoneNumber];
```

keep in mind that there are some %20 and %25 in the URL, maybe it causes the problem...

the string i get in the NSLog is:

> feedURLString = [http://192.168.50.204:8080/webapi/originate?sofia/internal/408220'set:effective_caller_id_number=722772408,bridge:sofia/gateway/012smile/0545890183@212.199.220.21'](http://192.168.50.204:8080/webapi/originate?sofia/internal/408220%27set:effective_caller_id_number=722772408,bridge:sofia/gateway/012smile/0545890183@212.199.220.21%27)            93610576nline2@2@

Answer (score 2, accepted):

remove the %20 and %25 from the string
then use the stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding command from NSString

```
string = [sURL stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

Answer (score 0):

You're right, the %20 are almost certainly causing a problem.

Any places in the string you want an actual % symbol in the result, you should be writing %%.

Another option that some people use is to leave the %s as they are, but use stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:withString: to do the substitiation.

eg:

```
NSString *str = @"http://{HOST}/{USER}/blah";
str = [str stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:"{HOST}" withString:hostname];
str = [str stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:"{USER}" withString:username];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try writing the url with the normal characters instead of %20 and %25, then add in your variables, and when you have the complete url string use

```
[feedURLString stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEndocing];
```

Edit: sorry for double, I guess the anwser was obvious :)